# Placing SD-Card Image into LinearLayout ImageView

Tags: android, android-canvas, loadimage

I have an application which is some kind of MiniPaint which means I can draw images and  save them to my sd-card. Now I would like to add some text options, using an XML Linear Layout. My idea is switching to an Activity with a XML view in wich I pretend to have an editText and a TextView (this will be enough to save my text) now want I want to know: How to combine my XML and just created Drawing?  I'm thinking about placing an ImageView with my drawing in it which will take about 1/3 or 1/2 of the screen.  But I have no idea how to load an Image from sd-card to my imageView.  is it possible?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is how you do it:

```
setContentView(R.layout.notas);

    ivImagen = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);
    myUri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/MisDibujos/Dibujo_1.png");
    ivImagen.setImageURI(myUri);
```

(Just in case that someone needs this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `ImageView` use its `setImageURI(...)` method.

You'll first need to create your `Uri` and use `parse(String uriString)` where the `uriString` parameter is something like `file://<path-to-image>`

Comment: Would you give me some extra information/example?  Excuse me but I don't know how to do it

Comment: I figured it out, this helped me because I had no clue!  I refered to the Uri article and understood what you were trying to tell me